# React JS, using parameters in onClick to change state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, onclick, setstate

I need to have parameters on my on click to send a string depending on what button someone clicks. I realized to set parameters i would need to create a function inside my `render () {}` but now when i try to use `this.setState({zone: location})` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles/homeStyle.css";
import timerIcon from "./styles/media/timer_clock.png";
import streaksIcon from "./styles/media/streaks_fire.png";
import guideIcon from "./styles/media/guide_meditation.png";

class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        zone: "home",
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="diagonal_shape"></div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12" id="title">
                        <h4 className="center-align">
                            Peaceful<span id="title_steps"> Steps</span>
                            <br />
                            {this.state.zone}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav_bar">
                        <div className="col s4" id="goto_timer">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={timerIcon} width="60%" alt="clock" onClick={() => goTo("timer")} />
                                <br />
                                Timer
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={streaksIcon} width="60%" alt="fire" onClick={() => goTo("stats")} />
                                <br />
                                Stats
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={guideIcon} width="60%" alt="meditating" onClick={() => goTo("guides")} />
                                <br />
                                Guides
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
        function goTo(location) {
            console.log("yes " + location);
            this.setState({ zone: location });
        }
    }
}

export default Main;
```

I am pretty sure this is because i can't use the this.setState({}) inside the render function, but i am at a loss in how i should get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting error is because you have defined a `function` inside render method after the return.

Note the word **function** here (not arrow fun). When you define a function the js engine will hoist it to the top of its scope with a value of undefined. Thats why you got the error.

Technically, you can define handler inside render method but you have to make sure to use an arrow function and define it before the render method return statement. [See demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-wiles-cdjw5?file=/src/App.js)

**HOWEVER**, as a best practice don't define handlers inside render method.

**Code snippet of writing handler inside render**

```js
export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "hello"
  };

  render() {
    console.log("state", this.state.name);
    const clickMe = () => {
      console.log(this.setState({ name: "hi!!!!" }));
    };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={() => clickMe()}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing `state` update in the function then You cannot define a function inside a class method. define the `goTo` method as the `class` method and then call it like `this.goto("some string")` on button click.

You need to `bind` `this` to the `goTo` method or just use `arrow function`.

```
class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            zone: "home",
        };
        this.goTo = this.goTo.bind(this);
    }

    goTo(location) {
        console.log("yes " + location);
        this.setState({ zone: location });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="diagonal_shape"></div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12" id="title">
                        <h4 className="center-align">
                            Peaceful<span id="title_steps"> Steps</span>
                            <br />
                            {this.state.zone}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav_bar">
                        <div className="col s4" id="goto_timer">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={timerIcon} width="60%" alt="clock" onClick={() => this.goTo("timer")} />
                                <br />
                                Timer
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={streaksIcon} width="60%" alt="fire" onClick={() => this.goTo("stats")} />
                                <br />
                                Stats
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={guideIcon} width="60%" alt="meditating" onClick={() => this.goTo("guides")} />
                                <br />
                                Guides
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
export default Main;
```

> If you want to use function within the `class` method and want to access the class `fields/methods` then bind the `class` `this` variable to the function or just use `arrow` function. With this the `this` variable inside the `function` will refer to `class`.

```
class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        zone: "home",
    };


    render() {

        function goTo(location) {
            console.log("yes " + location);
            this.setState({ zone: location });
        }
        goTo = goTo.bind(this);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="diagonal_shape"></div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col s12" id="title">
                        <h4 className="center-align">
                            Peaceful<span id="title_steps"> Steps</span>
                            <br />
                            {this.state.zone}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="nav_bar">
                        <div className="col s4" id="goto_timer">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={timerIcon} width="60%" alt="clock" onClick={() => this.goTo("timer")} />
                                <br />
                                Timer
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={streaksIcon} width="60%" alt="fire" onClick={() => this.goTo("stats")} />
                                <br />
                                Stats
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col s4">
                            <p className="center-align">
                                <img src={guideIcon} width="60%" alt="meditating" onClick={() => this.goTo("guides")} />
                                <br />
                                Guides
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );


    }
}
export default Main;
```

> I would suggest the first approach as it's more readable an clean.